# Getopt parsing error in bash script (option declaration mistake)

Tags: bash, getopt

I need to get 4 options (each with a short and a long version) in a bash script.

Here is what I did:

```
OPTS=`getopt -l :author,icon,channel,message: -o :aicm: -- "$@"` || 
exit 1
eval set -- "$OPTS"
while true; do
    case "$1" in
    -a|--author) echo "A:'$2'"; shift;;
    -i|--icon) echo "I:'$2'"; shift 2;;
    -m|--message) echo "M:'$2'"; shift 2;;
    -c|--channel) echo "C:'$2'"; shift 2;;
    --) shift; break;;
    *) echo Error; exit 1;;
    esac
done
```

And here is what I get:

command

```
docker run --rm -e SLACK_TOKEN slacker notify --channel foo
```

output

```
C:'--'
Error
```

Of course, I would like to have this output:

```
C:'foo'
```

Comment: So `slacker` is the command you are working on and whose code is included above?  Your code looks vaguely like you are using `getopts` and then reimplementing it yourself with a `while` loop.

Comment: To clarify, slacker is the docker image name I'm building. It contains a bash script named notify from which I extracted the above code. I should have simplified the call part to be more focused on my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getopt` command looks a little funky.  You seem to be using `:` as some sort of delimiter, here:

```
-l :author,icon,channel,message:
```

And here:

```
-o :aicm:
```

That doesn't make any sense.  The `:` has special meaning in the options definitions; take a look at the `getopt(1)` man page:

> `-l, --longoptions longopts`
>
> The  long (multi-character) options to be recognized.  More than one
>   option name may be specified  at  once,  by  separating  the names
>   with commas.  This option may be given more than once, the longopts
>   are cumulative.  **Each long option name in longopts  may be followed
>   by one colon to indicate it has a required argument, and by two colons
>   to indicate it has an optional argument.**

The same is true of short options.

So assuming that all of your options take arguments, you would write:

```
OPTS=`getopt -l author:,icon:,channel:,message: -o a:i:c:m: -- "$@"` ||
```